# PHP form just refreshes if the page has been open a while

Tags: php, forms, centos7, vps, http-status-code-302

This is a weird one and I really need help figuring it out! We're using a CentOS VPS for all of our sites if that makes a difference. Our business makes custom web apps for businesses and sometimes these are left open for 30+ minutes before a form is submitted.

The problem we're having is that if the form is left open for a while (I don't know the exact time but it it's 20+ minutes, I'm sure) when you submit the form it will just refresh the page and doesn't send any data, etc. Hitting refresh doesn't ask you to resubmit the form data or anything like that.

Here's the code for the form:

```
<form action="/workorder/edit/" method="post">
    <div class="col-md-12 padded-sm">
        <label>Notes:</label>
        <textarea name="notes" class="form-control" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 padded-sm">
        <label>Choose Hourly Rate:</label><br>
        <div class="radio radio-success">
            <input type="radio" name="rate" value="standard" id="checkoutrate-standard">
            <label for="checkoutrate-standard">Standard</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio radio-success">
            <input type="radio" name="rate" value="overtime before 8" id="checkoutrate-otbefore8">
            <label for="checkoutrate-otbefore8">Overtime Before 8pm</label>
        </div>
         <div class="radio radio-success">
            <input type="radio" name="rate" value="overtime after 8" id="checkoutrate-otafter8">
            <label for="checkoutrate-otafter8">Overtime After 8pm</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 padded-sm text-right">
        <input type="submit" name="checkoutsubmit" class="btn btn-success" value="End Time">
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is the simple PHP code that runs when the form is submitted:

```
$checkoutsubmit = $_POST['checkoutsubmit'];
if($checkoutsubmit):
    $checkinid = val_db($_POST['checkinid']);
    $notes = val_db($_POST['notes']);
    $rate = val_db($_POST['rate']);
    $sql = "UPDATE workorders_labor SET userid='$userid',endtime='$time',notes='$notes',rate='$rate' WHERE id='$checkinid'";
    $db->query($sql) or die($db->error);
    $_SESSION['success'] = "You have successfully checked out of the job.";
    redirect("/workorders/edit/");
endif;
```

I'm 99% sure it's not a problem with the code because it works perfectly fine when you load up the page, fill out that form and submit it. But if you load up the page, let it sit for a while and then fill out that form and submit it it just refreshes the page.

I've only been able to reproduce the issue a couple of times but one of my clients consistently has the issue.

**Worth Noting:**

No errors from PHP that I can see. No DB errors. No success message from the `$_SESSION['success']`. It seriously looks like it's just not sending the data at all.

I recently moved these clients over from a GoDaddy VPS to another VPS provider. Same version of PHP, same version of CentOS... as far as I have been able to find all of the Apache settings are the same (but it's possible they aren't and I'm just not looking for the right one).

This also ONLY happens if the page is left open for a while before submitting the form. Loading the page and submitting the form after a couple minutes is fine. Letting the page sit for 30 minutes, refreshing it and then filling out the form and submitting is fine. Letting the page sit for 30 minutes and then filling out the form without doing anything else and it just refreshes the page.

The clients who have the issue are using an iPad and we've been able to reproduce on our Macbooks... could it be an Apple related issue? But seems to happen on Macbook whether it's Chrome or Safari.

**UPDATE**

After using the suggestion in the comments of Chrome's Network tab in developer tools here is what is happening:

You load the page and get a 200 OK status.
Let the form sit for 30 minutes and then submit the form. 
Get a 302 Temporary Redirect status & automatically go back to the same page with 200 OK status.

Chrome's Network tab basically shows this:

- /workorders/edit 200 OK - *initial load*
- --all of the JS, css, etc--
- /workorders/edit 302 Temporary Redirect - *after submitting the form*
- /workorders/edit 200 OK - *immediately after the 302 error*
- --all of the JS, css, etc--

If I don't let the form sit for a while (~30 minutes in my test case) it returns 200 on initial load and 200 on submitting the form and then when the form finishes processing and redirects it gives 200 again.

**UPDATE #2**

In response to suggestion in the comments I copied the Curl request from the 302 response in Chrome's developer tools and sent that Curl request from Postman. I tried this three times - once waiting just a few minutes and once waiting 30 minutes, and again another 30 minutes later and all three times returned 200 OK and posted the data. It appears sending as Curl does not return 302.

**UPDATE #3**

While I didn't FIX the issue I did figure out a way to avoid it happening while I try and figure out what the root cause is. This may help diagnose what's happening. I am thinking it may be on the server side because of this and not anything to do with the actual PHP code.

To get around it I have the page using jQuery's `$.get(url,function(data){})` function just shooting to a blank page I called `session_keep_alive.php`. I have it on an interval to get that page every 5 minutes. When that is running the problem never happens with the form (at least after testing 3 times / 1.5 hours... previously I could reproduce the issue 100% of the time if I waited 30 minutes before submitting the form).

So I can only assume it may be something on the server end and not with the PHP code. It's like the server is forcing the 302 when the session has sat for 30 minutes or so. Any thoughts on a permanent fix compared to the workaround above?

Comment: Is the PHP code you've shown *all* of the code, or is there something that runs before this? For example, do people have to log in to the site, and there's a session that gets checked before processing?

Comment: Try to find a way to reproduce this consistently, even if it means waiting 20+ mins. When you do, keep the network tab open in Chrome's developer tools to see what the request and response look like. Then, look at your server's request logs (however you must do that) and see if you're actually getting hit.

Comment: Try and log the `$_REQUEST` variable somewhere (if it doesn't contain confidential information. Try and reconcile that against server logs too - does the page actually submit a POST request? Secondly - your SQL looks vulnerable to an SQL injection. Best sort that out!

Comment: @Ben - Thanks I'll try give that route a try along with the others mentioned. The `val_db()` function on the POST variables protects against SQL injection. Thank you. @Greg - There is **a lot** that goes on beforehand. They are required to be logged in, there's a session that gets checked against the database for ensure the login is valid, etc.

Comment: Are you sending the form to same page ?

Comment: Like Ben and Charlie said, open your network tab on Chrome with _Preserve log_ enabled, and see what your requests look like. Make sure you're posting correctly. Use `var_dump($_REQUEST)` in your PHP if you have to. Also, how does your `redirect()` function look like?

Comment: @jerome - Yes, it's being sent to the same page. The PHP then catches the form, processes it, gives success message and redirects back to the same page again. 

@sykez - Redirect function is just an easier way to do a PHP header redirect. Instead of having to type out `header("Location: /blah/blah/")` I can type out `redirect("/blah/blah/")` or `redirect("some_keyword")` that goes to a specific page.

When I have some time to let the page sit for 20+ minutes at a time I'll run it with Chrome's network tab open & dump the `$_REQUEST` if need be.

Comment: If the form is being passed to the same page you need to use the `<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>` to your `form` action attribute. And remove the redirection.

Comment: @jerome - Sorry but I don't understand why either of those are needed? Can you let me know more about the reasoning for that? The URL the form is going to is the same page - no need for `PHP_SELF` if I don't mind typing in the URL, right? Also removing the redirection would allow for the user to be able to hit CTRL+R or back and it asking for them to resubmit the form which would be horrible. The redirect ensures this won't happen so it redirects to itself.

Comment: @ben - After using Chrome's network tab and letting the form site for 30 minutes before submitting it I was able to replicate the issue. When I originally load the page it gives a 200 OK status. When I submit the form it give the same page a 302 Status and then immediately refreshes/moves back to the same page with a 200 OK status. Any idea what might be causing that?

Comment: That's very odd. With inspector open you can right click and copy the request as Curl. If you run it in Curl with debug mode does it continue to give you a 302?

Comment: @Ben - I did what you suggested and send the Curl request through Postman. I did this twice.. the first time was within a couple minutes of getting the 302 response and it returned 200 OK. So I waited 30 minutes and sent the Curl again and got a 200 OK again. It appears sending as Curl does not respond with 302. I'll run another test in another 30 minutes. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Ben - Did it again another 35 minutes later via Curl and it responded 200 OK and submitted the form data properly again. So it does seem like Curl is working okay and it's only returning the 302 after it sits a while on a browser.

Comment: Are you able to isolate the exact network request in Chrome that causes the redirect? I'm thinking that there could be something on the page (or a cookie or something) that ultimately ends up causing PHP to redirect. Are you using any frameworks? Does the same thing happen with a local copy of the application?

Comment: @Ben - After playing with it and looking at code differences between our old server and this one I am thinking it -has- to be something in the PHP that checks to make sure the session is active. The problem is that if the script was thinking it wasn't active it would redirect to the login page - not back to the same page again. The framework is a custom framework we built (something super simple) for our specific use. We don't develop on local environments only directly on the VPS's. I will do some more checking on my session checking scripts to see if I can figure it out...

Comment: @Ben - After playing with things further and checking the code I could not find anything different that would be causing it compared to what I had on the old server. The custom framework is a bit different but the login session checking, etc, was all exactly the same. I think it may have something on the server side and I found a workaround that 'fixes' it... check my update on the original post for more info. Any help you can give if you have any advice would be greatly appreciated. I'd like to have a permanent fix compared to the temp fix I put in place for our clients.